# how could you create a transparent user filesystem

Tags: installation, filesystems, uninstall

I would like to know how you could create a root filesystem on a rom image but have it transparently linked to a users home folder.

I wish to create a symbolic link to usr/bin within the users home directory for installation and uninstallation purposes, but also like how both osx and windows have their programs directory in the home directory, but I don't know how to create a transparent user filesystem.

I know about xdg, for the desktop, documents directories, etc. But I want to know how to create a hidden programs and system directory, while keeping the rootfs hidden.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't exactly be hidden, but you might be able to use the `unionfs` driver to create what you want. It allows two filesystems to be virutally "merged", with all write operations going to the one which has higher priority. Many linux line CDs use this to create a virtual FS on a ramdisk where a user can install programs, but back that filesystem with the pre-installed applications on the CD. This is necessary because the user can't write to the CD.

Comment: Is there any docs or examples that would explain how to use unionfs within a single hierarchy, not on a cd, but on hdd?  Also, I would like to ask about unionfs-fuse, which one would be better for me to use?